# how to create the custom function in angular for officejs

Tags: excel, office-js, excel-web-addins

I am using officejs to build excel addin. I have created the task pane application using Angular 8. Now i want to create custom function which will use most of the functionality implemented in taskpane. can I use the same taskpane application to also create the custom function? Also can someone provide me an example of how to create custom function in angular, till now I could only see the example in typescript or in javascript. also can i use services in angular such as HTTP to fetch the data from external source

Comment: Yes you can have a taskpane and custom functions in the same addin. When using Yeoman and generator-office the default template does exactly that. Why would you want to use angular for your custom functions ? Just put the services that the taskpane and custom function are using in a helperfile and import it in both

Comment: because my taskpane is developed in angular, most of the services or class uses angular service for e.g. HTTPClient angular service is used to fetch the data, just want to make use of it.